# Printing from a method

Tags: java

```
public class Simple2DArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public static void fill()
    {
        int[][] grid = new int[5][5];
        for(int r=0;r<grid.length;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<grid[r].length;r++)
            {
                grid[r][c] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            }
        }
    }
    public static int biggest(int[][] grid, int big)
    {
        for(int r=0;r<grid.length;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<grid[r].length;r++)
            {
                if(grid[r][c]> big)
                {
                    big = grid[r][c];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(big);
        return big;
    }
}
```

I would like for it to print big. How do I do this? I tried putting `System.out.println(biggest(null,big)` in the main method but that did not work.

Comment: What is your requirement? Fill function you are using or not? If you are calling biggest(null,big) then you have to check for null inside biggest.

Comment: `fill` is never called, also it doesn't return the array so it gets lost. Make `fill` return `grid` and hand this over to `biggest`. Initialize `big` somewhere.

Comment: Please consider to upvote and/or accept the answers you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in your code.

```
public class Simple2DArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] grid = fill();

    System.out.println(biggest(grid, 20));

}

public static int[][] fill()
{
    int[][] grid = new int[5][5];
    for(int r=0;r<grid.length;r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<grid[r].length;c++)
        {
            grid[r][c] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Input 2D");

    for(int r=0;r<grid.length;r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<grid[r].length;c++)
        {
            System.out.print(grid[r][c]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }

    return grid;
}

public static int biggest(int[][] grid, int big)
{
    if (grid != null) {
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                if (grid[r][c] > big) {
                    big = grid[r][c];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return big;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the changes made? Currently it's a code only answer (which is fine)...Having a brief explanation would make it more useful (such as the answer by [Chai T. Rex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342751/printing-from-a-method/47343097#47343097) which expands on the changes made to their respective code).

Answer (score 1):

The following corrections need to be made:

1. `fill` needs to return `grid`.
2. `biggest` doesn't need `big` as a parameter (it makes little sense). It should start out as `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
3. There's no need to print `big` within `biggest`.
4. In your `for` loop that loops through values of `c`, you should have `c++` instead of `r++`.

```java
public static int[][] fill()
{
    int[][] grid = new int[5][5];
    for(int r=0;r<grid.length;r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<grid[r].length;c++)
        {
            grid[r][c] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        }
    }
    return grid;
}

public static int biggest(int[][] grid)
{
    int big = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int r=0;r<grid.length;r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<grid[r].length;c++)
        {
            if(grid[r][c]> big)
            {
                big = grid[r][c];
            }
        }
    }
    return big;
}
```

Then you can call `biggest` on an actual two-dimensional array (`null` isn't an actual two-dimensional array):

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] array = fill();
    System.out.println(biggest(array));
}
```